# unable to add content lookup field

Tags: salesforce

Is there a way to create a lookup field to content on a custom object?  For example, I have a custom object called "Materials Presented", which is the detail object to a custom object "Call Report" that is the master object.  I want to include a lookup field to "Content" on the "Materials Presented" object.  Is this possible?

So, a Call Report record can have many Material Presented records that are pointing to different content records.

I see no way to create this relationship.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.